# Error in Stateful Convolutional LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, stateful

I want to implement a Stateful Convolutional LSTM in this way:

```
# build CNN/LSTM and train it.
#
model = Sequential()

# build CNN/LSTM and train it.

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same'), input_shape=(210, 22, 26, 1))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(Conv1D(16, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=8))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, batch_input_shape=(32, 26, 16), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, stateful=True))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
adammgm = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adammgm, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


# saves the model weights after each epoch
# if the validation loss decreased
#
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath= odir_a + "/temp_lstm_model_weights-{epoch:02d}.h5")

model.fit_generator(generate_reduced_dimension_arrays_from_file(ilist_a, edfroot_a, featroot_a, labroot_a, feat_ext_a, lab_ext_a, num_channels_a, feat_fdur_a, win_len_a,    models_order, lstm_batch_size_a, NEDC_DEF_BATCH_FILE), steps_per_epoch=NEDC_DEF_STEPS_PER_EPOCH, epochs=lstm_epoch_size_a, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

But I got this error when I wanted to implement this structure:

*ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, it needs to know its batch size. Specify the batch size of your input tensors: 
- If using a Sequential model, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_input_shape` argument to your first layer.
- If using the functional API, specify the time dimension by passing a `batch_shape` argument to your Input layer.*

I real all the posts but I still do not know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Add a `batch_input_shape` to your first layer...

Comment: I added to the first layer of CNN. I also added to all the layers. I always receive the same error.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you add it? One important thing about it is that, different from other shapes, this one needs to include the batch size.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved. The solution is using the batch_input_shape instead of input_shape in the first layer of CNN:

```
# build CNN/LSTM and train it.
#
model = Sequential()

# build CNN/LSTM and train it.

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same'), batch_input_shape=(32, 210, 22, 26, 1))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(Conv1D(16, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=8))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, stateful=True))) 
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
adammgm = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adammgm, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```